# Exception 'nil FIRApp instance passed to databaseForApp.' was thrown while invoking on on target RNFirebaseDatabase with params in react native

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native

I am new to setting up firebase in react native and I want to initialize a second configuration in firebase but I am having an error.

This is my code:

```
const secondaryAppConfig = {
      apiKey: ...,
      authDomain: ...,
      databaseURL: ...,
      projected: ...,
      storageBucket: ...,
      messagingSenderId: ...,
      appId: ...,
      measurements: ...
    };

    const secondaryApp = firebase.initializeApp(secondaryAppConfig, 'secondary');
    secondaryApp.database()
      .ref(`test`)
      .on('value', (snap) => {
        const test = snap.val();
        console.log(test.sample);
      });
```

This is the error that shows:

**Exception 'nil FIRApp instance passed to databaseForApp.' was thrown while invoking on on target RNFirebaseDatabase with params (
    SECOND,
    "...",
        {
        appName = SECONDARY;
        eventType = value;
        hasCancellationCallback = 0;
        key = "...";
        modifiers =         (
        );
        path = test;
        registration =         {
            eventRegistrationKey = "...";
            key = "...";
            registrationCancellationKey = "...";
        };
    }
)**